# XSLT not displaying node name if use variable from another variable

Tags: xml, xslt

### My XSLT have like below :

```
<xsl:param name="file1" select="document('Category.xml')"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

     <xsl:variable name="JobCategory" select="normalize-space(user:replaceCategoryChar(JobCategoryId))" />
     <xsl:variable name="JobOccupation" select="normalize-space(user:replaceCategoryChar(JobOccupationId))" />


     <xsl:variable name="y"><xsl:value-of select="$file1//feeds/MedicalHealth/Nursing/JobCategoryId" /></xsl:variable> 

     <xsl:variable name="z"><xsl:value-of select="concat('$file1//feeds/',$JobCategory, '/' ,$JobOccupation,'/JobCategoryId')"/></xsl:variable>

</xsl:template>
```

---

**Sample XML**

---

```
<MedicalHealth>
        <Nursing>
            <JobCategoryId>XX</JobCategoryId>
        </Nursing>
</MedicalHealth>
```

---

Question and Issue:
- JobCategory fetch text from different query which is coming fine. ( i.e. MedicalHealth )
- JobOccupation fetch text from different query which is coming fine. (i.e. Nursing )

when i print variable "y" it pick the value from XML correctly. i.e. ::  XX
however when i try to print variable "z" is print the xPath as it is. i.e. : $file1//feeds/MedicalHealth/Nursing/JobCategoryId

I tried to put something like below

Gives error that $ at $JobCategory : Unexpected token '$' in the expression.

Can someone help on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with XSLT as far as i know. For Example:

> I want to get the value of a variable whose name is equal to the
>   value of the "id" attribute found in the current node. You can't.
>   There is no way in XSLT of constructing XPath expressions (e.g.
>   variable references) at run-time.

Your example is similar to the above statement. Please See the reference: http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/nono.html#d1874e40